# What is the correct grammar for "neither x nor y"?

Tags: grammar, translation, negation

I have searched on the web and found about 4 patterns (probably more) to say

> I am neither a student nor a teacher.

in Japanese.

> A: 僕は学生でもないし、先生でもない。
>
> B: 僕は学生でもなく、先生でもない。
>
> C: 僕は学生でもなければ、先生でもない。
>
> D: 僕は学生でも、先生でもない。

The x parts in A, B, C use negation but the x  part in D does not. It sounds confusing, right?

Shortly speaking, what is the correct grammar for "... neither x nor y ..." in Japanese?
For the sake of generalization, other examples that I want to translate into Japanese:

1. I neither smoke nor drink alcohol. (verb)
2. I am neither smart nor diligent. (adjective)
3. He works neither fast nor slowly. (adverb)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A: 僕は学生で**もないし**、先生で**もない**。
>   B: 僕は学生で**もなく**、先生で**もない**。
>   C: 僕は学生で**もなければ**、先生で**もない**。
>   D: 僕は学生で**も**、先生で**もない**。
>   what is the correct grammar for "... neither x nor y ..." in Japanese?

I think 「～も～もない」「～もないし～もない」「～もなく～もない」「～もなければ～もない」 are all correct, natural, and commonly used. To me, 「～もなく～もない」 sounds a bit literary, 「～もなければ～もない」 sounds a bit literary and emphatic, and 「～もないし～もない」 sounds a bit colloquial.

So I think you can use all these four formats for your other examples:

> I neither smoke nor drink alcohol. (verb)
>   →
>   A: 私はタバコ**も**吸わ**ないし**お酒**も**飲ま**ない**。/ タバコ**も**やら**ないし**お酒**も**やら**ない**。
>   B: 私はタバコ**も**吸わ**ず**酒**も**飲ま**ない**。/ タバコ**も**やら**ず**酒**も**やら**ない**。
>   C: 私はタバコ**も**吸わ**なければ**酒**も**飲ま**ない**。/  タバコ**も**やら**なければ**酒**も**やら**ない**。
>   D: 私はタバコ**も**酒**も**やら**ない**。*
>
> I am neither smart nor diligent. (adjective)
>   →
>   A: 私は賢く**もないし**勤勉で**もない**。
>   B: 私は賢く**もなく**勤勉で**もない**。
>   C: 私は賢く**もなければ**勤勉で**もない**。
>   D: 私は賢く**も**勤勉で**もない**。
>
> He works neither fast nor slowly. (adverb)
>   →
>   A: 彼は仕事が速く**もないし**遅く**もない**。
>   B: 彼は仕事が速く**もなく**遅く**もない**。
>   C: 彼は仕事が速く**もなければ**遅く**もない**。
>   D: 彼は仕事が速く**も**遅く**もない**。

Of course there are other options as the other posters have said.

---

In the last example you meant to use adverbs "fast" "slowly", but they're translated to i-adjectives 「速く(ない)」「遅く(ない)」... so here's another example:

> 佐藤さんは深く[潜]{もぐ}れない + 長く潜れない。
>   →
>   A: 佐藤さんは深く**も**潜れ**ないし**長く**も**潜れ**ない**。
>   B: 佐藤さんは深く**も**潜れ**ず**長く**も**潜れ**ない**。(maybe a bit awkward?)
>   C: 佐藤さんは深く**も**潜れ**なければ**長く**も**潜れ**ない**。
>   D: 佐藤さんは深く**も**長く**も**潜れ**ない**。

---

*To use two different verbs in format D 「～も～もない」, it'd be like:

> 「聞きも読みもしない」
>   「食べも飲みもしない」
>   「タバコを吸いも酒を飲みもしない」
>   etc.

but

> 「聞くことも読むこともしない」
>   「食べたりも飲んだりもしない」
>   「タバコを吸うことも酒を飲むこともしない」
>   「タバコを吸ったりも酒を飲んだりもしない」
>   「タバコを吸いもしないし、酒を飲むこともしない」
>   etc.

might sound more natural, as in @永劫回帰 and @Earthliŋ's posts.

Answer (score 3):

I think it works pretty much the same for the sentences you left untranslated.

> (僕は)タバコを吸うことも酒を飲むことも、しない。
>   (僕は)賢くもなく、勤勉でもない（者だ）。
>   (彼は)仕事は、速くもなく遅くもない。

The last one is not so pleasant and I would maybe say this:

> 彼は仕事が速いとは言えないけど、遅いとも言えない（です）。
>   彼は仕事が速いとは言えないけど、遅いというわけではない（です）。

The pattern in English either ... or, neither ... nor clearly maps to も...も. I can't see any exception. You might want to use すら or さえ instead of も in certain occasions but も should always be enough to convey the meaning of (n)either ... (n)or.

EDIT:
速い or 早い: http://career.mag2.com/hassou/080612.html

I changed the kanji for はやい to be more faithful to the OP intention of "fastness" but I still as discussed in the link above it clearly depends on what point you want to focus: "doing your job fast" or "doing your job quickly".

Comment: 速い = fast, 早い = early

Comment: @SingleFighter 早い is tolerated when something is shortly done.

Comment: 「(彼の)仕事のやり方は、早くもなく遅くも…」「彼は仕事をやるのは早い…遅い…」→ 普通は「彼は**仕事が早い** (速い?) / **仕事が遅い** 」という表現を使うような気がします

Comment: @chocolate なるほど。けれど、知りませんでしたので、よりくどい言い方にしました。直します。