# both...and, neither...nor

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct translation in Japanese?

> He both sings and plays the guitar.
>   彼は歌うのもギターを弾くのもする。
>   彼は歌いもギターを弾きもする。
>
> He neither sings nor plays the guitar.
>   彼は歌うのもギターを弾くのもしない。
>   彼は歌いもギターを弾きもしない。

Thank you

Comment: related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37021/4216

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your sentences look correct or natural, I am afraid to say.  To say these, 「歌{うた}を歌う」 is more natural than just 「歌う」.

> both ~~ and ~~

「歌{うた}も歌{うた}うし、ギターも弾{ひ}く」

「歌も歌って、ギターも弾く」

「歌も歌い、ギターも弾く」

Informally, you could say:

「歌もギターもやる」

> neither ~~ nor ~~

「歌も歌わないし、ギターも弾かない」

「歌も歌わなくて、ギターも弾かない」

Informally:

「歌もギターもやらない。」

Comment: Thank you, l'électeur. And if there is the verb "to like", for example "he likes both to sing songs and to play guitar" or "he doesn't like neither to sing songs nor to play guitar", which is the correct translantion? 彼は歌を歌うのもギターを弾くのも好き（です）。 and 彼は歌を歌うのもギターを弾くのも好きじゃない（です）。?

Comment: So in Japanese is it sufficient to change を with も in order to change meaning of the sentence, from "and" to "both...and" and to "neither...nor"?