# ~ことがある for more than one thing

Tags: grammar, usage, syntax, particle-が

In the Genki II textbook, there is a phrase that goes like this:

> うめぼし，のりなどを見たこと**も**聞いたこと**も**ありませんでした。

Now, I understand that this roughly means that "I've never seen or heard of pickled plums or nori algae.", but I was wondering why there is no が particle in the sentence.

The "basic" structure sentence for having the experience of something is

> ~ことがあります。

Since there are two things that are being referred to, I would have written it something like this:

> うめぼし，のりなどを見たこと**も**聞いたこと**が**ありませんでした。

I know this probably isn't correct, but can someone explain in to me? Why is there no が particle in the original sentence?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/37021/what-is-the-correct-grammar-for-neither-x-nor-y

Comment: Since there is symmetry in 'both A and B', you use 'も' twice: 'Aも Bも'. (Same with neither.) Also see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46730/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 〜も〜もない or　〜も〜もありません

is a very commonly used phrase to express two negative verb consecutively. In English it's like saying 'Neither have I seen it nor heard of it.' Although it doesn't always have to be negative

> あれもこれも〜

Roughly translate to 'This and that are all...',「も」is used when you want to group few things together and sounds more inclusive. On the other hand「が」
directly points at a single thing/object. And lastly...

> 〜も〜がありません

As you mentioned is an improper use of 「が」in your example, but

> 今日**も**時間**が**ありません ("I don't have the time today too")

Is correct since が points at the noun 'time'. I guess it is a completely different use case, but it is an useful phrase.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that も can replace が when using いる/ある constructions like that.

> > 犬**が**いる。猫**が**いる。
> >
> > 犬**も**猫**も**いる。